# Modify an existing regex to match '.' aswell

Tags: regex

I'm currently using this regex `^[A-Z0-9 _]*$` to accept letters, numbers, spaces and underscores. I need to modify it to allow `.`

Comment: "To allow `.` (period)"? Or is there something missing in your question?

Comment: I figured that leonyx wants a "." or he's had a heart-attack before being able to finish the sentence

Comment: @Panda Then how did he submit the questions‽ This is mysterious...

Comment: @PandaWood: No, then he obviously would have written "I need to modify it to allow Aaargh!"

Comment: O @Tim, perhaps he was dictating.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to allow period (`.`), just add it to the character class.

```
^[A-Z0-9 _.]*$
```

A period inside a character class is treated literally which means there is not need to escape it. But escaping it as:

```
^[A-Z0-9 _\.]*$
```

is also correct and many use it. [**Check it out**](http://www.rubular.com/r/e76IOM1PH3).

The following regex matches `\` and `.` aswell.

```
^[A-Z0-9 _\\.]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow period? add `\.` inside the []

Edit: TIL inside square brackets periods don't need to be escaped in regex.

So just a `.`, no `\`

Comment: Not quite ... inside square brackets, there is no escaping. A plain `.` by itself will work. Adding `\.` inside square brackets will accept either the \ character or the `.`.

Comment: Bah, I was only one character off ;-) Thanks!

Comment: @codaddict Weird, I thought Paul's answer was correct at first, but I tried it in Vim's search and it did match backslashes as well. Your link is for Ruby regexes. I just tried Python regexes and they work with Paul's example. It's only Vim that treats it literally.